# How to automatic intent to other activity like from SplashActivity to other Activity with timer?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, timertask

How to automatic intent to other activity like from SplashActivity to other Activity with timer using Kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

You can use handler to have deferred work queued.

```
 android.os.Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
         // This will execute after 5 seconds(5000 milliseconds)
         // val intent  = Intent(context, Destination::class.java)
         // startActivity(intent) 
         // finish()   
      }, 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use handler with delay, after delay  navigate to other Activity and call finish() in your SplashActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this sample. It will help you.

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            final WindowInsetsController insetsController = getWindow().getInsetsController();
            if (insetsController != null) {
                insetsController.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
            }
        } else {
            getWindow().setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            );
        }

        handler.postDelayed(() -> {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, TermsScreen.class));
            finish();
        }, 1000);

    }
}
```